# Reading the full file name using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have this code:

```
for dir in "/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/alexa"/*
do
  echo $dir
  value=`cat $dir`
  echo value
done
```

and the first file in the directory has the name as below:

```
amazon_alexa_february_7__2017_at_0504pm (2).txt
```

The output I get is:

```
/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/alexa/amazon_alexa_february_7__2017_at_0504pm (2).txt
cat: /Users/vskumar/Dropbox/alexa/amazon_alexa_february_7__2017_at_0504pm: No such file or directory
cat: (2).txt: No such file or directory
```

Basically, it is treating everything after space as another file name. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes around your variables to prevent word splitting and globbing:

```
for dir in "/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/alexa"/*
do
  echo "$dir"
  value=`cat "$dir"`
  echo value
done
```